# Can't connect my app with postgres inside a docker container

Tags: python, postgresql, docker

app_dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt /app

RUN pip3 install -r /app/requirements.txt

ADD sqlalch.py /app/sqlalch.py

CMD [ "python3", "sqlalch.py" ]
```

my_compose.yml

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  postgres_db:
    image: postgres:14.2
    container_name: postgres_db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=mydb
      - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
    expose:
      - "5432"
    #ports:
    #  - "5432:5432"
    volumes:  
      - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - mynet

  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: app_dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
    restart: always
    links:
      - postgres_db:postgres_db
    networks:
      - mynet

volumes:
  postgres_data:

networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
```

Python script sqlalch.py

```
from sqlalchemy import (create_engine, Column, Integer,
                        String, Date, desc, ForeignKey)
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker, relationship
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base


DATABASE_URI = 'postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@postgres_db:5432/mydb'

engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URI)
Session = sessionmaker(engine)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()


class Book(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'books'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = Column(String(30))
    author = Column(String(30))
    pages = Column(Integer)
    published = Column(Date)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.title}, {self.author}, {self.pages},{self.published}\n'


class Library(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'library'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    city = Column(String(50))
    street = Column(String(80))
    state = Column(String(50))

    book_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('books.id'))
    book_rel = relationship('Book')

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.id}, {self.city} - {self.book_rel}\n'


Base.metadata.create_all(engine)


def instert_books():
    title = str(input('Book title name: '))
    author = str(input('Book author name: '))
    pages = int(input('Book pages: '))
    published = str(input('Book published data (M/D/YYY): '))
    book = Book(title=title, author=author, pages=pages, published=published)

    session.add(book)
    session.commit()


def instert_library():
    city = str(input('City: '))
    street = str(input('Street: '))
    state = str(input('State: '))
    book_id = str(input('Book id: '))

    libr = Library(city=city, street=street, state=state, book_id=book_id)

    session.add(libr)
    session.commit()


def view_the_table():
    books = session.query(Book).order_by(desc(Book.published)).all()
    print(books)


def view_library():
    library = session.query(Library).order_by(Library.book_id).all()
    print(library)


# instert_books()
# instert_library()

# view_the_table()

view_the_table()
view_library()
```

$ docker ps -a

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                          PORTS      NAMES
2cfe63663c36   app_app         "python3 sqlalch.py"     16 minutes ago   Restarting (1) 36 seconds ago              app_app_1
5f4936a55286   postgres:14.2   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   16 minutes ago   Up 16 minutes                   5432/tcp   postgres_db
```

$ docker run -ti app_app /bin/bash

```
root@f52dc749e0ed:/app# ls
requirements.txt  sqlalch.py
root@f52dc749e0ed:/app# python3 sqlalch.py
```

RESULT

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 143, in _do_get
    return self._create_connection()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 256, in _create_connection
    return _ConnectionRecord(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 371, in __init__
    self.__connect()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 665, in __connect
    with util.safe_reraise():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
    compat.raise_(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 207, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 661, in __connect
    self.dbapi_connection = connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 590, in connect
    return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 597, in connect
    return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 122, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
        Is the server running on host "postgres_db" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Cannot assign requested address
        Is the server running on host "podtgres_db" (::1) and accepting
        TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

I do not make sense :(
I tried everything and it's not working but quickly works when I set the ports: 5432:5432 and set localhost:5432 in python script with my host machine but not with docker host.

What can I do wrong, does anyone have any idea;

Comment: The `docker run` command doesn't see the Compose networks or any of the other settings.  Do you get similar output from `docker-compose logs app`?  I'll note that `links:` is unnecessary and activates an obsolete Docker networking mode, and on some other SO questions it's seemed to help to remove that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer David, this is the output: app_1          | [jim, jim, 87787,1990-01-01
app_1          | ]
app_1          | []
app_1          | [jim, jim, 87787,1990-01-01
app_1          | ] It seams running and return the result, but how can run manual?

Comment: I saw returns result with this command: 'docker-compose -f my_compose.yaml run app' [jim, jim, 87787,1990-01-01
]
[]

Comment: OMG yes thank you, I did it, with 'docker-compose -f my_compose.yaml run app /bin/bash', Thank you very much David!

Comment: Just `docker-compose up -d` should do it; not `run` (so it respects the image's `CMD` and the Compose `ports:`), and you don't need the interactive shell.